# Question ban bug. How can I report it?

Tags: support, post-ban

I have been banned from asking questions on Stack Overflow, but after I read really much about this ban thing, it seems that this could be a bug. I have only one closed question, and a deleted one. Besides, I have more than 10 normal questions, and some upvoted. I really am in a struggle, because I read that I shouldn't just write to a moderator for such a small thing, and I don't want to get banned completely for doing so.

I know I should answer other questions, but I'm a beginner in programming.

EDIT:
This question is not about asking how to get out of ban, this is about ban bugs and how to report them.

Comment: I see 8 questions. 2 of which have had downvotes and have been deleted - these also count.

Comment: I do suggest you make edits to your currently open questions and improve them - get a few upvotes there and you should be able to get out of the ban fairly quickly.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't check it correctly then. Do you think this ban is absolutely correct?

Comment: The **automatic** ban kicked in as intended. You may have simply been a bit unlucky with it, being on the edge of being banned.

Comment: 3 closed questions and, according to the mods, 2 downvoted deleted questions, and only two questions with a positive score (and only 3 upvotes between the two).  Doesn't seem like a bug to me.  You're currently at 2/5/1 in terms of good/bad/neutral questions.

Comment: The only Answer you have can be improved explaining a bit more *why* that code solves the problem. Linking to official documentation is also welcome. See [answer] and dig some old, unanswered and interesting Questions, they're nice to learn and some random upvotes are mostly bound to happen.

Comment: Thank you for all your answers. I will keep these in mind. I got an up vote for one of my older questions, and that was enough for the ban to lift.

Comment: There is **no bug**. You were question banned because the algorithm heuristics did their work correctly. I'm glad to hear that you managed to come out of the ban so quickly, but do be careful with future questions.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In your specific case, [please contact us](https://stackoverflow.com/contact).

Comment: ... for this particular case, right? This not being general advice for most cases ....

Comment: @Bart Of course. This is a meta post about a specific case, so the answer applies to this specific case.

Comment: The comment was highly rhetorical. You never know when it becomes a search result. ;)

Comment: @Bart The ellipses compel me to respond. ;)

Comment: Well, there's already "My question or answer was denied" option so guess it can be used a general advice. (@Time FYI as well)

Comment: @ShaWizDowArd: Well look at this, I had no idea...interesting.

Comment: @ShaWizDowArd That's there for unusual cases. The *first* stop for anyone who's blocked isn't to email us. :) Our typical advice through that channel echoes the help center/meta post anyway.

Comment: That wasn't an ellipsis, an ellipsis is three dots - he has four!

Comment: @Flyk Well, it could be. The 4 dots is either, 4 periods, or an ellipsis and a period

Comment: it's incorrect grammar to include a period after an ellipsis!

Comment: @Flyk it's also incorrect grammar to have 4 periods ;). It's also incorrect grammar to not start these sentences with capitals, but we did it anyway. In any case it was intended to be an ellipsis. :)

Comment: Technically incorrect is still incorrect! Oh, ok, I'll stop :(

Comment: @Flyk Off-by-one is a common affliction.